# REQUEST_URI not found in environ in django oscar

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, django-oscar

I am complete newbie in django and this is the first time I want to deploy a django project. I am trying to deploy django-oscar's sandbox project with gunicorn and nginx. I used oscar's deployment script for nginx and wsgi and i modified them to match my needs, here they are:

wsgi.py:

```
import os
import sys
import site
import urllib

sys.stdout = sys.stderr

# Project root
root = '/home/ashkan/setak/setak/sites/sandbox'
sys.path.insert(0, root)

# Packages from virtualenv
activate_this = '/home/ashkan/setak/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

# Set environmental variable for Django and fire WSGI handler
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
_application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

def application(environ, start_response):
    environ['PATH_INFO'] = urllib.unquote(environ['REQUEST_URI'].split('?')[0])
    return _application(environ, start_response)
```

nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name setakshop.ir;

    # set_real_ip_from 192.168.125.252;
    # real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;

    # Ensure only one domain
    if ($host != 'setakshop.ir') {
        rewrite / $scheme://setakshop.ir$request_uri permanent;
    }

    access_log /home/ashkan/setak/setak/logs/nginx_access.log;
    error_log /home/ashkan/setak/setak/logs/nginx_error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip_types text/plain application/xml application/x-javascript text/javascript text/css application/x-json application/json;

        client_max_body_size 3M;
        keepalive_timeout 5;

    location =/robots.txt {
                root /home/ashkan/setak/setak/sites/sandbox/public/static/;
                expires max;
        }
    location =/favicon.ico {
                root /home/ashkan/setak/setak/sites/sandbox/public/static/oscar/;
                expires max;
        }
        location /media/ {
                alias /home/ashkan/setak/media/latest/;
                expires max;
        }
        location /static/ {
                root /home/ashkan/setak/setak/sites/sandbox/public;
                expires max;
        }
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/ashkan/setak/run/latest/uwsgi.sock;
        uwsgi_send_timeout 5;
        include uwsgi_params;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
}
```

now the error I get whenever somebody enters the website is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ashkan/setak/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 130, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/home/ashkan/setak/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 171, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/home/ashkan/setak/setak/sites/sandbox/wsgi.py", line 22, in application
    environ['PATH_INFO'] = urllib.unquote(environ['REQUEST_URI'].split('?')[0])
KeyError: 'REQUEST_URI'
[2015-05-05 16:46:04 +0000] [12506] [ERROR] Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ashkan/setak/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 130, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/home/ashkan/setak/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 171, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/home/ashkan/setak/setak/sites/sandbox/wsgi.py", line 22, in application
    environ['PATH_INFO'] = urllib.unquote(environ['REQUEST_URI'].split('?')[0])
KeyError: 'REQUEST_URI'
```

I printed the environ and os.environ dictionaries and I didn't see any entry with key REQUEST_URI.

how can I fix this? should I edit the wsgi script or should I fix environ dictionary to contain REQUEST_URI key? how can I do dat?

thanks in advance.

update: since I am using a virtualenv to deploy this project, and the activate script I'm using to activate the virtualenv is setak/bin/activate, I think the problem might be in wsgi.py where it sets the activate_this variable. But still have no idea how to fix this!

update2: this is the previous config for nginx which too didnt work. I wrote that myself from a tutorial, and then when that didnt work I switched to the version that oscar proposed.

```
server {
    server_name setakshop.ir;

    access_log off;

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/ashkan/setak/setak/sites/sandbox/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you modified `wsgi_params` file? By default there is a line `uwsgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;`

Comment: Why are you doing this? What's the point of all that mucking around with the WSGI environment? django-oscar is just a Django project, it doesn't need anything special for deployment; you should just be following the standard Django deployment docs.

Comment: no I have not. where can i find it and how should it be modified or what should i check? @AlexeyTen

Comment: @DanielRoseman that is the default wsgi script for django-oscar that Im using. I cannot not use this, since gunicorn gets a wsgi script as a parameter in deployment.

Comment: Sorry, are you using uwsgi or gunicorn? Your nginx conf implies uwsgi.

Comment: I am using gunicorn, but I dont think thats the problem. because the settings used to be set for gunicorn too, ill update the post with that settings now.

Comment: REQUEST_URI is generally only something that is set and used by Apache and thus is only relevant to mod_wsgi. The gunicorn WSGI server provides the same but under a different name within the environ dictionary. Don't recollect right now what the name is. In general though you shouldn't be overriding PATH_INFO with anything from REQUEST_URI as the latter isn't normalised and you could potentially open yourself up to various problems. Why do you need to override PATH_INFO?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I actually used the script provided by django-oscar people for deployment. what you said maybe true and seems like a logical answer, but I don't know why they did this because I dont exactly know their architecture. I just need to deploy this asap. What do you propose I should do? to deploy oscar's sandbox on gunicorn and nginx?